# how to add ngx-clipboard (or any similar library) to JHipster 6.10 Angular 10-based application?

Tags: angular, jhipster, ngx-clipboard

So, I've tried with already 3 or 4 different ngx-* libraries, that promise to give capability to copy page content to Clipboard. Here's how it goes with `ngx-clipboard`, which seems to be the most up-to-date of them all, and promises Angular 10 support.

Steps:

1. clone `jhipster-sample-app`
2. run `.mvnw`, then `npm start`
3. run `npm install ngx-clipboard --save`
4. add the module to imports, in `app.module.ts`:

```
import { ClipboardModule } from 'ngx-clipboard';
...
imports: [
...
    ClipboardModule,
...
]
```

4. added data model field to `home.component.ts`:

```
  fakeValue = 'hi clipboard';
```

5. added input and button to `home.component.html`:

```
        <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="fakeValue"/>

        <button ngxClipboard [cbContent]="fakeValue">Copy</button>
```

6. click Save; the project re-build will be triggered, with following errors emitted:

```
ERROR in src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.html:30:30 - error NG8002: Can't bind to 'cbContent' since it isn't a known property of 'button'.

30         <button ngxClipboard [cbContent]="fakeValue">Copy</button>
                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

7. and of course, "copy" button does not *copy* anything.

Question: what am I doing wrong?

PS: this branch (https://github.com/62mkv/jhipster-sample-app/tree/ngx-clipboard) contains all of the changes, described above.

PPS: `npm run build` emits the same error (+ also error about the template, which is a consequence of the above mentioned error)

Answer (score 0):

Actually, this specific problem seems to be quite a typical problem, related to the fact that nearly all of the README-s for library are only ever mentioning `app.module.ts`,
while JHipster application is split into many modules, alongside `app.module.ts`. Which is immensely confusing for people without any Angular proficiency to speak of...

Either way, this comment ([error NG8002: Can't bind to 'formGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. In Angular 9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60397268/error-ng8002-cant-bind-to-formgroup-since-it-isnt-a-known-property-of-form#comment106842860_60397268)) actually gives the most specific answer:

a dependency must be imported into each module separately, so in my case, importing it into `home.module.ts` instead of `app.module.ts` solved the problem!

Comment: glad you figured it out. You should have a sharedModule and import it. This is a common practice from Angular doc.

Comment: unless I'm wrong, shared-libs.module.ts exists for this reason in JHiipster apps.

Comment: @GaëlMarziou yes, that seems to be right on the spot!